# Displaying information from shops

Tags: javascript, react-native

To display all the shops, I get data from a database (Firestore) and push them into array and `setState`, and use map to display shops from `this.state{ shops }`.

This is working okay, but I am wondering if there are better ways.

````
export default class Shop extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shops: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const querySnapshot = await db.mShopsCollection().get();
    const shops = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const shop = {
        id: doc.id,
        address1: doc.data().address1,
        address2: doc.data().address2,
        address3: doc.data().address3,
        name: doc.data().name,
        prefecture: doc.data().prefecture,
        zip_code: doc.data().zip_code,
      };
      shops.push(shop);
    });
    this.setState({ shops });
  }

  render() {
    const { shops } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        {shops.map((shop) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleShowMap} key={shop.id}>
            <View>
              <View>
                <Text>{shop.name}</Text>
                <Text>
                  〒
                  {shop.zip_code}
                  {'\n'}
                  {shop.prefecture}
                  {shop.address1}
                  {shop.address2}
                  {'\n'}
                  {shop.address3}
                </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```
````

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of improvements you can make in your `componentDidMount`.

First, you create an empty array of `shops`, then push to it in every iteration over the `querySnapshot`. When constructing an array by transforming another array (or array-like collection), the appropriate method to use is [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can get an array of documents from the snapshot by accessing its `.docs` property.

Second, rather than calling `doc.data` many times repetitively, you can make an array of properties and extract each of them from the document being iterated over, putting them into a new object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const querySnapshot = await db.mShopsCollection().get();
  const properties = ['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'name', 'prefecture', 'zip_code'];
  const shops = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    const data = doc.data();
    return {
      id: doc.id,
      ...Object.fromEntries(properties.map(prop => data[prop]))
    };
  });
  this.setState({ shops });
}
```

Lodash's [`pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) is another method that can be used to extract certain properties from an object into a new object.